# Select an entire column minus header row in an Excel macro

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros, vba

How would I access a range that corresponds to an entire column starting at row 2 (there is a header row)?

The end of the selection should be the last non-empty cell in the column.

Answer (score 5):

See the Microsoft Support article *[How to select cells/ranges by using Visual Basic procedures in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291308)*, #19 (*How to Select an Entire Range of Contiguous Cells in a Column*).

Comment: That selects over a million rows in the workbook i'm using even though everything beyond 300 or so are blank.

Comment: how about: Sub LastCellBeforeBlankInColumn() / Range("A1").End(xldown).Select / End Sub

Answer (score 4):

[Referring to this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6301665/row-number-of-last-cell-with-data/14390619#14390619), the only safe method is the `.find()` method.
All other methods may give wrong results if you previously deleted some cells.

Example to get the last cells

```
Lastrow =  Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row
Lastcol =  Cells.Find("*", [A1], , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
```

And a specific answer to your question (assuming your data is in column 2, starting at row 2)

```
Range([B2], [B:B].Find("*", [B1], , , xlByRows, xlPrevious)).select
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Range(Range("A2"),Range("A2").End(xldown)).Select
```

or this:

```
Range(Range(Cells(2, 1), Cells(2, 1)), Range(Cells(65535, 1), Cells(65535, 1)).End(xlUp)).Select
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Excel keyboard shortcuts. Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd>.

This would take you to the cell A1 (if you have not used the freeze pane). Come one cell down and then use the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Down arrow</kbd> buttons to select until the last entered row.

If you have to select the column value, use the <kbd>right arrow</kbd> button instead of the <kbd>down arrow</kbd> button.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code averages everything but the header with the header in Cell "B1"

```
Dim GG as Long
GG = Application.WorksheetFunction.Average(ActiveSheet.Range("B2", Range("B2").End(xlDown)))
```